# Dynamically change the year when calculating date ranges using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple code to determine if the current date is part of the Fiscal Year 2014 or not. It sets a range between October 1, 2013 to September 30, 2014. Any date in that range will be considered Fiscal Year 2014:

```
var FYFirst     = 2013,
    FYLast      = 2014,
    beginningFY = new Date(FYFirst,9,1), //October 1
    endFY       = new Date(FYLast,8,30), //September 30
    todayDate   = new Date();
if (todayDate > beginningFY && todayDate < endFY ) { alert("FY 2014"); }
else { alert("Not this FY"); }
```

I would like to dynamically change FYFirst and FYLast. The way I wrote it, every October I would have to come and change it manually. I would appreciate any new ideas. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do to get the starting year is to go back one from the current year whenever the current month is earlier in the year than October:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
var FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear(); 
if (todayDate.getMonth() < 9) {
    FYFirst -= 1;
}
var FYLast = FYFirst + 1;
```

If it's after October, then the starting year is the current year. You can also do this in one line, but I'm not sure I'd advise it:

```
var FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear() - (todayDate.getMonth() < 9);
```

Comment: Thanks to lwburk, Yogesh and Jeremy for your suggestions, they all answer my question one way or another. At the end I decided to go with lwburk suggestions witha small modification:                                                    `var todayDate = new Date(),
FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear(); 
if (todayDate.getMonth() > 9){FYFirst += 1;}
var FYLast = FYFirst - 1;` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the current Fiscal year.

```
var today = new Date();
var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
var FYFirst, FYLast;
if(currentMonth < 9)
{
    FYFirst = currentYear-1;
    FYLast = currentYear;
}
else
{
    FYFirst = currentYear;
    FYLast = currentYear + 1;
}
console.log(FYFirst);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86td/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you need for any arbitrary year:

```
var todayDate = new Date(),
    FYFirst,
    FYLast,
    beginningFY,
    endFY;
if (todayDate.getMonth() < 9) {
    FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear()-1;
} else {
    FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear();
}
FYLast = FYFirst + 1;
beginningFY = new Date(FYFirst,9,1); //October 1
endFY = new Date(FYLast,8,30); //September 30
if (todayDate > beginningFY && todayDate < endFY ){
    alert("FY " + FYFirst);
} else {
    alert("Not this FY");
}
```