# Create custom year, different to calendar year? JS/QML

Tags: javascript, qt, date, qml

I am trying to change the 'first day' and 'last day' of a year (normally 01/01/yyyy - 31/12/yyyy), to my own defined dates, being:

**First Day:** 01/04/yyyy  (1st April)

**Last Day:** 31/03/yyyy (31st March)

I have found a similar question/answer here:

[Dynamically change the year when calculating date ranges using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846264/dynamically-change-the-year-when-calculating-date-ranges-using-javascript)

with the answer being:

```
var todayDate = new Date();             //18/05/19
var FYFirst = todayDate.getFullYear();  //2019 
if (todayDate.getMonth() < 3) {         // earlier than april
    FYFirst -= 1;
}
var FYLast = FYFirst + 1;
```

But where my users are storing dates taken out of an allowance, I need this to extend forward/back at least 2 years, so the above code would be `currYear (01/04/2019 - 31/03/2020)`.

There would also be (currently being, but needs to by dynamic):

**prevPrevYear:** 01/04/17 - 31/03/18
**prevYear:** 01/04/18 - 31/03/19

**nextYear:** 01/04/20 - 31/03/21
**nextNextYear:** 01/04/21 - 31/03/22

In which the date is taken from the allowance of `currYear,nextYear` of whatever year the saved date falls into.

In this example let's say a users yearly 'allowance', is 40, and each day counts as 1, so when saving a date this deducts 1 from the allowance. I have all the math working for this, but need some way for the app to know if its deducting from this years 'allowance' or next years ect, this is written and stored to a Database - all of the math for this is currently working but rolls indefinitely without any yearly end!

**My question is**
How would I extend the above, to take into consideration the multiple year span needed when my users are storing dates? I am building my app using `Felgo`, working with QML!

Comment: What do you mean by "taken out of an allowance".

Comment: How do you intend to represent the new dates? Should 1 April become 1/1, 1 May become 1/2, to 1 March become 1/12?

Comment: Hi @selfie I've updated my question with some expansion on allowances, hope this helps!

Comment: @RobG thanks for the response, April 1st would still be 01/04/yyyy, but is where the deductions would flip to the next/nextNextYear for user allowances - I've also added further expansion to this in my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your year range is 1 Apr to 31 Mar the following year. You might call 1 Apr 2019 to 31 Mar 2020 "2019". You can create a simple function so that any date from 1 Jan to 31 Mar belongs to the previous year, e.g.:

```js
function getMySpecialYear(date) {
  var yr = date.getFullYear();
  var fyStart = new Date(yr, 3, 1);
  return date < fyStart? yr - 1 : yr;
}

[new Date(2019,0,1), // 1 Jan 2019 -> 2018
 new Date(2019,5,1)  // 1 Jun 2019 -> 2019
].forEach(date => console.log(date + ' - ' + getMySpecialYear(date)));
```

You can then sum the days for a particular range/year and see if the total is less than or greater than the allowance for that range/year.

Some places have a similar issue in that the financial year runs from 1 July to 30 June, they are often called things like "FY 2019/20".